# Failing to close connection after running sql query, how detrimental?

Tags: mysql

When manually running an sql query from an app server, if a user just clicks the X to close the window instead of using F12 or the menu to close the connection to the DB, what kind of negative impact can there be?
.
Is there an automatic timeout for connections?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout of a MySQL connection is defined in the /etc/my.cnf file in the `wait_timeout` server system variable. It's defaulted to 28800 (seconds) - we usually set it for our clients to a very low value - ranging from 10 seconds to 60 seconds. So, if you leave a connection unclosed, then it'll close, by default, after 28800 seconds (that's very high if you have a large number of clients using the app).

In your case, `interactive_timeout` doesn't apply, since you are not really using the console.

Comment: TYVM. That's the answer I needed. I'm assuming it's the same concept from UNIX to Windows, even if it's set by GUI or something.